# Grass Gis: What is the meaning of a TARGET LOCATION?

Tags: grass-gis, orthophoto, orthorectification

I am attempting to follow a guide on creating ortho-photos in Grass GIS, available here:

https://grassbook.org/extra/sample-chapter/

The chapter suggests that a separate cartesian LOCATION should be used for un-georeferenced images, and that the image group should have the projected LOCATION set as its TARGET LOCATION.

The following step requires that the image group have an elevation model set, for which the DEM would be in the projected location. However, it doesn't seem like I can access things which are in other locations, and it doesn't really make sense to have a projected DEM with my unprojected images, and vice versa.

I have read before that starting the orthorectification process with unreferenced images is a normal way to do it, but I can't seem to make any progress.

What does setting the target do, and how can I move forward?

Comment: The DEM is telling the system the heights of each pixel of the DEM. The geographical position of the pixels must be known and therefore DEM must be projected. What does not make sense is an unprojected DEM because it would mean "the height of this pixel is 842 meters above the see, but I do not know where on the earth that pixel is".

Comment: I agree, that doesn't make sense. But the i.ortho.elev module is not letting me select my DEM which lives in the projected location. And it doesn't seem like I can access my unprojected images which I am in the projected location. So I really don't understand how to work between different locations, which is what the book is telling me to do